# Using JQuery's draggable with isotope tiles not working (fiddle included)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to combine jquery's droppable functionality:

http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

With isotope:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html

to get some draggable tiles.  I have the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/24/

If you try and drag and drop one of the tiles, you get some odd behavior.  It's as if the reversion is seeing bogus default positions... though the same happens if I don't set "revert" so I think it's something in isotope.

I'm not sure if this is some kind of conflict between the libraries or an implementation mistake... any idea how I can correct this?

Here's my javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.study-box',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });
});
$(function () {
    $(".set-box").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
    });
$(function () {
    $(".folder-box").draggable();
    $(".folder-box").droppable({
        revert: "invalid",
        accept: ".folder-box", 
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert("dropped");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working by adding some code according to this post:

http://jstarrdewar.com/blog/2013/02/24/an-example-using-jquery-ui-draggable-with-metafizzys-isotope-plugin/

Here's the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/26/

```
code code code
```